# Как обратиться к полю другого класса, не потеряв значение в Typescript?

Tags: классы, typescript

*Для справки: пишу на TypeScript, в связке участвуют Ionic, Angular 2*

---

Есть компонент, содержащий в себе класс IngridlistPage со следующим кодом внутри:

```
export class IngridlistPage {
public dbingrids: string = "test";
constructor() {};
}
```

Есть второй компонент, содержащий в себе класс IngridsearchPage со следующим кодом внутри:

```
import { IngridlistPage } from '../ingridlistpage'
export class IngridsearchPage {
 ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log(IngridlistPage['deb']);
 }
}
```

Вывод в консоли после загрузки страницы IngridsearchPage: undefined. Пробовал геттером вытащить значение, пробовал инициализировать в конструкторе, а объявлять вне него, пробовал объявлять аргументом конструктора, пробовал обращаться через .prototype
Если вывести только IngridlistPage, то выводит объект, в котором есть свойство dbingrids, но если обращаться только к нему, выводит undefined. Если обращаться напрямую IngridlistPage.dbingrids, то выводит: "property does not exist on type 'typeof IngridlistPage'

Создать объект на основе класса и обращаться к свойству новоявленного объекта могу, ошибок не вызывает, только мне данное решение не подходит, т.к. в классе IngridlistPage есть методы, которые работают со строкой dbingrids. Ведь если я захочу добавить ингредиент в IngridsearchPage, а потом удалить его в IngridlistPage, **я должен работать с одной и той же строкой**.

Большое спасибо за уделенное моему вопросу внимание.